# Problems with innerHTML in a javascript function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json

I'm writing this code for one of my class, where I need to generate some code in html using localStorage and some JSON element. Everything go well, but when I want to sent the code I've generate in the innerHTML of the div and ol, nothing happens. Here my function, sorry for bad english by the way I'm french.
My function is supposed to go throught the JSON array and showing every element that is in the same categorie as Cate. and then it'S going to create a order list of every element and a section with each product.

```js
function afficherProduit(Cate){
 produitArr = localStorage.getItem("Produit");
 if(produitArr == null){
  alert("Aucun produit enregistré.");
 }else{
  var contenuPage="";
  var contenuListe ="";
  produitArr = JSON.parse(produitArr);
  alert("on est ici" + JSON.stringify(produitArr));
  longueurArr = produitArr.produit.length;
    alert("on est ici2");
  for(i = 0; i < longueurArr;i++){
   if(produitArr.produit[i].categorie == Cate){
    alert("Correspondant trouvé");
    contenuListe += "<li><a href='#"+ i +"'>"+produitArr.produit[i].nom+"</a></li>";
    contenuPage += "<section id='"+i+"'><header><h2>" +produitArr.produit[i].fabriquant + "<a href='#haut' class='retour'>(retour haut)</a></h2></header><figure><figcaption><h3>" + produitArr.produit[i].nom;
    contenuPage += "</h3></figcaption><img src='images/'"+ produitArr.produit[i].photo+"' width='200px' height='200px'/><p>" + produitArr.produit[i].description + "</p></figure><footer class='foot'><hr/><a href='#fin'>Fin de la page</a></footer></section>";
   }
  }
  //ERREUR ICI QUELQUE PART.
  alert(contenuListe)
  x = document.getElementById("listePrincipale");
  alert("element trouve");
  x.innerHTML = contenuListe; //This is where it stop....
  alert("On vient de traversé le premier champs");
  document.getElementById("contenuPagePrincipale").innerHTML = contenuPage;
  alert(""+contenuListe+"");
 }
 
}
```

The alert are here to help me know where the code stop and what's in the variable. I know this might be a stupid mistake, but so far I've no idea what it is and how to solve my problem...
Here is my HTML code that's gonna use the function...

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="fr">

<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8" />
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles/stylecat.css" />
 <script type="text/javascript" src="JS/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="JS/localstorage.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="JS/logo.js"></script>
 <script> afficherProduit('Console'); </script>
 <title>Producto - Consoles</title>
</head>

<body>
 <!-- Section En-tête -->
 <header>
 <a href="index.html"><canvas id="Logo" width="200" height="100" ></a>
  <h1>Producto Pour Tous</h1>
  <hr/>
 </header>
 <!-- Section Contenu -->
 <section id ="haut">
  <header><h2>Consoles :</h2></header>
  <figure>
   <ol id="listePrincipale">
   </ol>
  </figure>
 </section>
 <div id="contenuPagePrincipale">
 </div>
 <footer id="fin">
 <hr/>
 </footer>
</body>

</html>
```

Thanks for your help, I'm a begginner in Html and javascript by the way sorry if my code is bad!

Comment: You can place both your HTML and JS in a single snippet, that way we can see the execution.

Comment: This is quite easy, you're calling the function in the head, before any of the elements are available in the DOM. Just move the script tag that calls the function down to right before `</body>` instead.

Comment: Holy cr/$ it work!!! Thanks man you're awesome!!

Comment: Along those lines, a more common approach is to use the onload event handler to trigger your function call.  That way, you are assured that your page is fully loaded before any javascript is ran.  <body onload="afficherProduit('Console')">

Comment: since you are using jquery, you can also use $(document).ready(function() {afficherProduit('Console);})